# Simple PHP registration form - worked for months, changed nothing, now mysql INSERT fails

Tags: php, registration

This registration form worked like a charm for months. I have changed nothing. Now, it gets through all the conditionals of duplicate name, email, and the password check, and then fails to `INSERT` mysql and returns the `"An error has occurred. Your account was not created."` I don't see why. Has syntax changed or what?

```
    <div id="backdrop"></div>
    <div id="register">    
    <img src="http://www.staketheclaim.com/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-c526a84/dropbox/2012/rotate/header<?php echo(rand(1,4)); ?>.png" style="margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -20px;" />
    <div id="regi" style="width:400px;float: right;">
    <?php 
        if ($username && $userid) {
         echo "<div id='log-re' style='margin-left: 6px;width: 413px;'><h2>You must logout to register a new account. Not your Account?</h2>" . "<br /><br /><div id='cta'><a href='http://www.staketheclaim.com/logout/' class='button' style='padding-left: 36px;font-size: 24px;top: 2px;right: -160px;'>Logout Now</a></div></div>";    
        }
         else {
    if ($_POST['registerbtn']) {
         $getuser = $_POST['user'];
         $getemail = $_POST['email'];
         $password = $_POST['pass'];
         $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];
         if ($getuser) {
             if(strpos($getuser, ' ') > 0 == false ){
             if ($getemail) {
                   if ($password) {
                         if ($getretypepass) {
                                if ( $password === $getretypepass) {
                                      if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))){
                                            require("base.php");
                                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                                 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                                $password = md5(md5("ss3verds4g".$password."ss357rd5sg"));
                                                $date = date("F d Y");
                                                $code = md5(rand());
                                        $bio = "Bio";
                                    $location = "Location";
                                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                                              '','$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date', '$bio', '$location', '1'
                                                         )");
                                                         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                                         $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                                         if  ($numrows == 1){
                                                               $site = "http://www.staketheclaim.com";
                                                               $webmaster = "noreply <noreply@staketheclaim.com>";
                                                                $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                                                 $subject = "Activate Your Account";
                                                                 $message  = "Thanks for registering. Click the link below to activate your account.\n";
                                                                 $message .= "$site/activate/?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                                                 $message .= "You must activate your account to login.";
                                                                 if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers )) {
                                                                          $errormsg = "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activition link send to <b>$getemail</b>.";
                                                                          $getuser = "";
                                                                          $getemail = "";
                                                                     }
                                                                        else 
                                                             else 
                                                                   $errormsg ="An error has occured. Your account was not created.";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg ="Their is already a user with that email.";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg ="Their is already a user with that username.";
                                            mysql_close;
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address to register.";
                                  }
                                  else
                                     $errormsg = "Your passwords did not match.";
                      } else 
                              $errormsg = "You must retype you password to register.";
                } else 
                       $errormsg = "You must enter a password to register.";
            } else
                  $errormsg = "You must enter you email to register.";
         } else
              $errormsg = "Your username cannot have any spaces.<br />";
      } else
          $errormsg = "You must enter a username to register.<br />";
    } $form = "<form action='' method='post' style='margin-top:-20px;'>
    <h2>Sign up for StakeTheClaim™.<br /> It's free!</h2>
    <br />
    <font color='red'>$errormsg</font>
    <br />
    <br />
    Username:
    <br />
    <input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' style='' />
    <br />
    <br />
    Email:
    <br />
    <input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' />
    <br />
    <br />
    Password:
    <br />
    <input type='password' name='pass' value='' />
    <br />
    <br />
    Re-Password:
    <br />
    <input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' />
    <br />
    <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />
    </form>";
    echo $form;
    }
    ?></div></div>
```

Comment: well your code is vulnerable to sql injection and xss...

Comment: Yeah, it is a pretty basic one. Got a better code/plugin that I can easily implement? Or perhaps something that can secure this code after fixing?

Comment: I think the first thing to do here is to understand what is happening in your code. Do you have any questions on how the code works at the moment?

Comment: You may want to perform some kind of change to the double md5 encoding method of the password (pretty lame method really). Look into `crypt()` for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible this is a mysql data type issue (well, limit really). You say it fails on `update` but I'm only seeing an `insert` statement.

What are the column types on the table `users` where the insert is being run?

Basically, if you reach the limit of the column type, the insert will fail. This would be consistent with what you have said.

Edit: Also, PHP is depreciating `mysql_*` calls. Shift to either `mysqli_*` or another alternative like `PDO`. The shift to `mysqli` for this code would be easy, but then your code needs for a full review, it is full of issues. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: The column types for users is VARCHAR(50) for the inputs.

Comment: What is the "limit" of the column type? Like if it is VARCHAR(50) and you put 70 characters or something else you are referring to?

Comment: Geez, I had one more column, so I forgot a '' at the end.

As the for the encryption how to I go about using crypt() in this situation.

Comment: All columns are VARCHAR(50)? Is there a primary key (often an `id` column). There should be no issue if *all* columns are varchar(50). As to the `crypt()`, try: http://php.net/crypt